# What is the best way to show the work flow of a single class with UML

Tags: code-analysis, uml

What is the best UML diagram type to use when trying to show how a class' behavior flows from one method to another?

I am trying to diagram existing code and the behavior I am looking at primarily involves private method calls, with a few calls to static objects outside the class. I don't feel that a sequence diagram would give the best detail in this case **since the class in question doesn't interact with any other classes except for the very few static calls mentioned earlier.**

What would fit best in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly you have 2 choices (per @Silli's answer): sequence or activity diagram.  I would probably have suggested sequence diag as first choice, however you say you don't think that's appropriate. Could you elaborate why?

Perhaps it's conditional logic?  If so an activity diagram may be the better choice.  It has more intuitive syntax for showing control flow than a sequence diagram.  You could also show the static objects in separate swimlanes - so clearly differentiating calls to external objects.  You can also illustrate parallel behaviour if that's relevant to you.  Some good examples [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html) if it helps.

hth.

Comment: I think an activity diagram is what I need for modeling my class analysis. [link](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) The link shows how to use parameters in an activity, so I think I can show the correct level of detail with an activity diagram.

Answer (score 3):

According to the UML Superstructure (http://www.omg.org/spec/UML), in the UML two kind of behaviors exist: emergent behaviors and executing behaviors.

*An executing behavior is performed by an object (its host) and is the description of the behavior of this object. 
An executing behavior is directly caused by the invocation of a behavioral feature of that object or by its creation. In either case, it is a consequence of the execution of an action by some related object. A behavior has access to the structural features of its host object. Objects that may host behaviors are specified by the concrete subtypes of the BehavioredClassifier metaclass.
Emergent behavior results from the interaction of one or more participant objects. If the participating objects are parts of a larger composite object, an emerging behavior can be seen as indirectly describing the behavior of the container object also. Nevertheless, an emergent behavior can result from the executing behaviors of the participant objects.*

You can model behaviors by means of Activities or Interactions (actually you may also use state machines and use cases). Activities are more adapt to model executing behaviors while Interactions to model emergent behaviors.

Now if your class has many parts and its behavior you want to model consists in a "complex" interaction of its parts then probably an interaction diagram (sequence) may be the right choice. Otherwise, if the behavior you need to model, consists of a sequence of atomic actions an activity may be better. Consider in UML there is a specific actions to represent the invokation of a method (CallOperationAction) which takes as input pin the object reference you can retrieve by means of a dedicated action (ReadSelfAction). There is also an action to read an object attribute (ReadStructuralFeatureAction). 
Also check the Foundational for Executable UML Models (FUML) http://www.omg.org/spec/FUML

Answer (score 1):

While all of the previous answers are correct, I would like to add the option of using a [State-Machine](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html) to define the behavior of the class. State machines allow you to show what is the current state of the class and how the state of the class changes as methods are called or events are received. Since you state that you are mostly modeling one class, I think the most important thing to show is what can be done (what method calls can be called) depending on the current state and how these method calls affect the state of the class. One think I really like about state machines is that they have relatively well defined semantics and also have ways to show information at different levels using composite and orthogonal states.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend collaboration diagram (UML 1.x) renamed to Communication diagram (UML 2.x).
This may be better than sequence diagram, better because it may be more readable in your case.

> A Communication diagram models the interactions between objects or parts in terms of sequenced messages. Communication diagrams represent a combination of information taken from Class, Sequence, and Use Case Diagrams describing both the static structure and dynamic behavior of a system.

[image]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram

Comment: It seems that a communication diagram would work best for me since it can specify messages to each object, but can specify each object as a function instead of an object?

Comment: AFAIK, you can simply write self-message - i.e. an object sending a message to itself (execution of a private method). Each bloc in the drawing is an object (or at least a class), not a function. Does this help ?